# How to make Serializer class for manytomany field to be empty on POST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The `ItemSerializers` is for the Model `Item` which is a `manytomany` field in the model `supplier` , am trying to make it not required , but it is not working ,, her is my code :

```py
class SupplierSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    person_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=120, allow_blank=True)
    company_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=120, allow_blank=True)
    tax_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=120, allow_blank=True)
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
        fields = '__all__'
```

the problem is in the line

```
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True, required=False)
```

AS I can't send a post a request with items field empty !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [**`read_only=True`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only)

```
items = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```